# After quantisation in neural network, will the output need to be scaled with the inverse of the weight scaling

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

I'm currently writing a script to quantise a Keras model down to 8 bits. I'm doing a fairly basic linear scaling on the weights, by assuming a normal distribution of weights and biases, and then interpolating all the values within 2 standard deviations of the mean, to the range [-128, 127]. 
This all works, and I run the model through inference, but my image out is crazy bad. I know there will be a small performance hit, but I'm seeing roughly 10x performance degradation.
My question is, after this scaling of the weights, do I need to do the inverse scaling operation to my output? None of the papers I've been reading seem to mention this, but I'm unsure why else my results would be so bad.

The network is for image demosaicing. It takes in a RAW image, and is meant to output an image with very low noise, and no demosaicing artefacts. My full precision model is very good, with image PSNRs of around 40-43dB, but after quantisation, I'm getting 4-8dB, and incredibly bad looking images.

Code for anyone who's bothered to read it

```
for i in layer_index:
    count = count+1
    layer = model.get_layer(index = i);
    weights = layer.get_weights();
    weights_act = weights[0];

    bias_act = weights[1];

    std = np.std(weights_act)
    if (std > max_std):
        max_std = std

    mean = np.mean(weights_act)
    mean_of_mean = mean_of_mean + mean


   mean_of_mean = mean_of_mean / count

max_bound = mean_of_mean + 2*max_std
min_bound = mean_of_mean - 2*max_std

print(max_bound, min_bound)


for i in layer_index:
    layer = model.get_layer(index = i);
    weights = layer.get_weights();
    weights_act = weights[0];
    bias_act = weights[1];
    weights_shape = weights_act.shape;
    bias_shape = bias_act.shape;
    new_weights = np.empty(weights_shape, dtype = np.int8)
    print(new_weights.dtype)
    new_biass = np.empty(bias_shape, dtype = np.int8)

    for a in range(weights_shape[0]):
        for b in range(weights_shape[1]):
            for c in range(weights_shape[2]):
                for d in range(weights_shape[3]):
                    new_weight = (((weights_act[a,b,c,d] - min_bound) * (127 - (-128)) / (max_bound - min_bound)) + (-128))
                    new_weights[a,b,c,d] = np.int8(new_weight)
                    #print(new_weights[a,b,c,d], weights_act[a,b,c,d])

    for e in range(bias_shape[0]):
        new_bias = (((bias_act[e] - min_bound) * (127 - (-128)) / (max_bound - min_bound)) + (-128))
        new_biass[e] = np.int8(new_bias)

    new_weight_layer = (new_weights, new_biass)
   layer.set_weights(new_weight_layer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont do what you think you are doing, I'll explain.
If you wish to take pre-trained model and quantize it you have to add scales after each operation that involves weights, lets take for example the convolution operation.
As we know convolution operation is linear in my explantion i will ignore the bias for the sake of simplicity (adding him is relatively easy), Let's assume X is our input Y is our output and W is the weights, convolution can be written as:

```
Y=W*X
```

where '*' represent the convolution operation, what you are basically doing is taking the weights and multiple them by some scalar (lets call it 'a') and shift them by some other scalar (let's call it 'b') so in your model you use W' where: `W'= Wa+b`

So if we return to the convolution operation we get that in your quantized network you basically do the next operation: `Y' = W'*X = (Wa+b)*X`

Because convolution is linear we get: `Y' = a(W*X) + b*X'`
Don't forget that in your network you want to receive Y not Y' at the output of the convolution therefore you must do shift + re scale to get the correct answer.

So after that explanation (which i hope was clear enough) i hope you can understand what is the problem in your network, you do this scale and shift to all of weights and you never compensate for it, I think your confusion is because your read papers that trained models in quantized mode from the beginning and didn't take pretrained model quantized it.

For you problem i think tensorflow graph transform tool might help, take a look at:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md

If you wish to read more about quantizing pre trained model you can find more information in (for more academic info just go to scholar.google.com:
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. So I've already tried to go down the tensorflow route, but I've no clue how to use tensorflow, and while I could quantise the model, I couldn't actually figure out how to pass my data into the model at inference. (A whole other issue).
As for the answer, are you saying I need to do a shift and rescale after every convolution, or just at the output of the model?
Or am I just entirely wrong in my approach?

Comment: Im saying that after each operation that involves weights you have to compensate the scale your are applying to the weights because you want the model original answer. You can create from your Keras model a tensorflow model (if you use TF as your backend) from there my suggestion to you is use graph transform and to read more about quantization, most of the information I found is in academic papers.

Comment: Yeah so as I said, I've tried going down the TF route. I've converted to a graph and quantised, but because I don't understand TF, I can't actually infer my model. Keras just takes in an image using model.predict(), but I can't get that to work in TF. That's why I'm trying to do in Keras.

You mention a compensation that needs to be applied to the weights, to get back to my original model.
How does the compensation get applied to the weights, in such a way that the weights are still getting scaled, but the output is not affected?
If you have any helpful papers, please link them.

Comment: The compensation will be applied to the result of the layer you will probably have to modify your model. I suggest you to learn TF if you wish to do effective deployment.